# OpenFileDialog - How to prevent the default directory from being overwritten?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I'm trying to find a way to reset the initial/default directory after closing an OpenFileDialog. Consider the following example:

```
using (OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    // Example: This opens in the 'Desktop' directory
    // User navigates to 'Documents' directory in the Form before selecting a file
    DialogResult result = openFile.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) MessageBox.Show(openFile.FileName);
}

// Somewhere else, this code then runs
using (OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    // Problem: This now opens in 'Documents' directory. Not good!
    // How to open using the same default directory (ie: Desktop)?
    DialogResult result = openFile.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) MessageBox.Show(openFile.FileName);
}
```

Just to be clear, 'Desktop' is just an example, I won't actually know the initial directory as it's stored in the registry (if I understand correctly).

I tried using the RestoreDirectory option. This did not seem to have any effect. From what I've read elsewhere it's supposed to reset the Environment.CurrentDirectory back to its original value, which sounds reasonable. However, I don't think OpenFileDialog even uses Environment.CurrentDirectory since the value is never changed, and never matches what OpenFileDialog opens with (unless I manually browse to it).

Is there anything I might be missing here? Does anyone know how to stop overwriting *whichever* directory variable OpenFileDialog uses as its default?

Comment: `openFile.InitialDirectory = yourPath;`

Comment: @LarsTech I specifically mentioned in my post that I don't have an initial directory.

Comment: It's not clear to me what directory you want to open to.  If the first time you use the dialog has the directory you want to open with, store it in a variable for the next time.

Comment: @LarsTech The directory is loaded from the registry, I am not setting it. And simply saving it in a variable and setting it everywhere is extremely impractical. Every other developer would have to remember to set it every single time they use a FileDialog, which defeats the entire purpose of using the registry.

Answer (score 0):

The default directory is stored in the following registry key on Windows 7.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32
```

IIRC, this could be different on other OS's, so you might want to find out the exact directory depending on your OS version.

So what you could do is to grab that value when your application launches, and save it in the memory, and set that to `OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory` every time before you open the dialog.

Comment: Bear in mind that retrieving such a value from the registry requires your application to have permissions to read the registry. In low trust environments or for enterprise applications, this may pose a problem.

Comment: Is there a way to set that value? I'd much rather reset the value after the first OpenFileDialog (since this particular piece of code is isolated from the rest of the app) than having to ensure every single OpenFileDialog throughout the entire app sets it. And I'm okay if other OpenFileDialog's use the default implementation, I don't want to prevent that.

Comment: @Gigabyte you're quite correct. OP must use this method only if he/she knows this is not going to be a problem.

Comment: @AnotherProgrammer I don't recommend _writing_ to the registry too often. A different approach I suggest is to create a local setting in your project that can hold a path, and then save your directory value to it the first time you use your OpenFileDialog, and then load from it every time your application is launched. I can post a code sample if you're interested in this approach.

Comment: @Sach Doesn't the OpenFileDialog write to the registry though? Ideally I'd rather just turn that off rather than running my own code to overwrite it a second time.

Comment: @Sach As for your second approach, it sadly won't work in my case since I am writing a library that other developers will be using in their apps. Doing this would require them to implement it throughout their application. I'd rather not have my library modifying this value at all if possible as it interferes with their application.

Comment: Well in that case, yes, my second approach won't work.

Answering your earlier question, yes you could write to the registry. But given that you won't even know how your clients would use this library, whether they'd have permission to write to the registry, you might still run into problems cautioned by @Gigabyte above. So, you may write to the registry, but might want to let your clients of the fact and advice them to be cautious.